# Use formset_factory as sub-form in Django crispy form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I've created an 'address' model that is used by a number of different parts of my application. Each user can have multiple addresses that belong exclusively to them. I've created another class - 'PersonalDetails' - that belongs to a user. I'd like this class to have at least one, but up to six addresses that belong to the user.

My current set up (involving crispy forms) allows this but the address field is a 'select' field containing the list of addresses currently belonging to that user. I'd like the user to be able to use existing addresses or create new addresses as they go. How do I make this happen? I've tried making the 'PersonalDetails' form use the 'AddressForm' but without any joy.

As an added bonus, I'd only like to render one address form initially but with the user having the option of clicking 'add more addresses' for further address fields. This sounded like a job for formsets but I don't know how that'll work with crispy - any help would be great!

**Address_models.py**

```
class Address(models.Model):

    # Relations

    profile = models.ForeignKey(
            Profile,
            verbose_name = "user"
    )

    # Attributes - Mandatory

    address_line1 = models.CharField(
            max_length = 45,
            verbose_name = "Address line 1"
    )
    city = models.CharField(
            max_length = 50, 
    )
    postcode = models.CharField(
            max_length = 8,
            verbose_name = "Postcode",
            help_text = "Enter your postcode",
            blank = False,
            validators = [RegexValidator(
                "[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][A-Z]{2}")]
    )

    # Attributes - Optional

    start_date = models.DateField(
            verbose_name = "Start Date", 
            blank = True, 
            null = True,
            help_text = "Move in date"
    )
    end_date = models.DateField(
            verbose_name = "End Date", 
            blank = True, 
            null = True,
            help_text = "Move out date"
    )

    address_line2 = models.CharField(
            verbose_name = "Address line 2",
            max_length = 45,
            blank = True,
            null = True
    )
    county = models.CharField(
            verbose_name = "County", 
            max_length = 40, 
            blank = True, 
            null = True
    )
```

**PersonalDetails_models.py**

```
class PersonalDetails(models.Model):

    # Relations
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
            Profile,
            verbose_name = "user"
    )

    # Attributes - Mandatory

    ni_number = models.CharField(
            max_length = 9,
            verbose_name = "National Insurance Number",
            help_text = "Enter your National Insurance number",
            validators = [RegexValidator(
                "^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]$")]
    )

    last_address = models.ForeignKey(
            Address
    )

    # Attributes - Optional

    prior_1_address = models.ForeignKey(
            Address,
            blank = True,
            null = True,
            related_name = "prior_1_address"
    )

    prior_2_address = models.ForeignKey(
            Address,
            blank = True,
            null = True,
            related_name = "prior_2_address"
    )

    prior_3_address = models.ForeignKey(
            Address,
            blank = True,
            null = True,
            related_name = "prior_3_address"
    )

    prior_4_address = models.ForeignKey(
            Address,
            blank = True,
            null = True,
            related_name = "prior_4_address"
    )

    prior_5_address = models.ForeignKey(
            Address,
            blank = True,
            null = True,
            related_name = "prior_5_address"
    )

    prior_6_address = models.ForeignKey(
            Address,
            blank = True,
            null = True,
            related_name = "prior_6_address"
    )
```

**Address_forms.py**

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'
```

**PersonalDetails_forms.py**

```
class PersonalDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonalDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalDetailsForm
        fields = ['ni_number', 'last_address', 'prior_1_address', 'prior_2_address', 'prior_3_address', 'prior_4_address', 'prior_5_address', 'prior_6_address']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using below widget succesfully.

```
class Formset(LayoutObject):
    """
    Layout object. It renders an entire formset, as though it were a Field.

    Example::

    Formset("attached_files_formset")
    """
    template = "%s/formset.html" % TEMPLATE_PACK
    def __init__(self, formset_name_in_context, template=None,**kwargs):
        self.formset_name_in_context = formset_name_in_context
        # crispy_forms/layout.py:302 requires us to have a fields property
        self.fields = []
        # Overrides class variable with an instance level variable
        if template:
            self.template = template

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK):
        formset = context[self.formset_name_in_context]
        html = ''
        return render_to_string(self.template, Context({'wrapper': self,
            'formset': formset}))
```

Add this widget somewhere in your application and use it like how you would other fields in crispy forms.
lets say your module is crispy_layouts

```
helper_content.append(
                      crispy_layouts.Formset('address_form')
                      )
helper = FormHelper()
helper.layout = Layout(
    helper_content,
)
```

address_form is a valid formset in your context.
it uses 
"%s/formset.html" template by default, you can customize it as your needs.

I am using the below template and bootstrap3

```
<div class="formset">
    <div class="table-scrollable">
        {{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
        <table class="table table-hover">
            {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {% endif %}
            <tr>
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <td> {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

                {{ field | as_crispy_field}}
                </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Add Row" name="addrow">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my template I allow people to add more rows, to do that, in your view. If your request.POST contains addrow then copy your request.POST to post_data, so it will be mutable.

```
post_data['addressform-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(post_data['addressform-TOTAL_FORMS'])+ 1
```

You basically increase TOTAL_FORMS variable and return that forms to user again as it is.

This is how you add more rows to your formset without javascript.